# CDate format recognition issue

Tags: excel, date, vba

The problem is simple: `CDate("Oct 01, 2015")` gives me `Type mismatch` error since I am working with a non-english setup. `CDate("Okt 01, 2015")` works just fine. The date format is `Mon DD, YYYY`.

What can I do to make Excel recognise the format without changing the language/location setup or doing some string manipulation?

Using an array for exchanging the name of the month just doesn't look fancy enough.

```
month_name(0, 0) = "Jan"
month_name(0, 1) = "Jan"
month_name(1, 0) = "Feb"
month_name(1, 1) = "Feb"
month_name(2, 0) = "Mar"
month_name(2, 1) = "Már"
month_name(3, 0) = "Apr"
month_name(3, 1) = "Ápr"
month_name(4, 0) = "May"
month_name(4, 1) = "Máj"
month_name(5, 0) = "Jun"
month_name(5, 1) = "Jún"
month_name(6, 0) = "Jul"
month_name(6, 1) = "Júl"
month_name(7, 0) = "Aug"
month_name(7, 1) = "Aug"
month_name(8, 0) = "Sep"
month_name(8, 1) = "Szep"
month_name(9, 0) = "Oct"
month_name(9, 1) = "Okt"
month_name(10, 0) = "Nov"
month_name(10, 1) = "Nov"
month_name(11, 0) = "Dec"
month_name(11, 1) = "Dec"

str = "Oct 01, 2015"

For counter = 0 To 11
    If Left(str, 3) = month_name(counter, 0) Then
        str = month_name(counter, 1) & Right(str, Len(str) - 3)
        Exit For
    End If
Next counter

day_date = CDate(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create it as a function that way it can be used by any other procedure

```
Option Base 1

Function Date_Translation(sDate As String) As Date
Dim aMth1 As Variant, aMth2 As Variant
aMth1 = [{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov", "Dec"}]
aMth2 = [{"Jan","Feb","Már","Ápr","Máj","Jún","Júl","Aug","Szep","Okt","Nov", "Dec"}]
Dim b As Byte
    For b = 1 To 12
        sDate = Replace(sDate, aMth1(b), aMth2(b))
    Next
    Date_Translation = CDate(sDate)
End Function
```

Comment: Glad it helps you, please acknowledge the answer and help us to keep the site updated and question completed...

Comment: Well to be precise the question is about to "recognise the format without changing the language/location setup or doing some string manipulation". According to that I am in doubt although thankful. Do you guys go for the green tick in a case like this?

Comment: There is string manipulation, though you have the idea already, it was certainly improved not just by a better setting of the arrays, the loop was shortened and set as a function. Nevertheless, it's up to you, my concern is more about all those questions that are still open just because what it was asked it's just not possible, even though good alternatives were proposed. Think of when we revisit a question that still waiting for “the right answer” and then we found that the answer provided is Ok and there is nothing else that can be done about it, nevertheless the question remains unanswered…

Comment: Nicely put! Thanks again!