# What datetime format does Cdate() return in VBA?

Tags: vba, date

I am converting strings into a date format in VBA. The string must first be parsed into date format (whilst still a string), before being cast to a date. E.g I must first transform "091220" to "09/12/20" and then call `Cdate()`

However, I cannot verify what datetime format is the default for `Cdate()`. The official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) and other sources such as [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdate.php) don't state the format that is returned. Primarily, does `Cdate()` return a date as `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`?

Other questions regarding `Cdate()` such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769300/cdate-format-recognition-issue) mention the format depends upon the region you are in. I am in the UK.

Through the use of a MWE, I have shown that `Cdate()` returns it as `dd/mm/yy`, however I would like to know for sure before I apply this function to the rest of my project.

I attach this MWE below.

```vb
public sub date_test()

dim early_date as string '9th June 2020
dim late_date as string '4th July 2020 

early_date = "090620"
late_date = "040720" 

early_date = format(left(early_date,2) & "/" & mid(early_date, 3, 2) & "/" & right(early_date,2), "dd/mm/yy")

late_date = format(left(late_date,2) & "/" & mid(late,3,2) & "/" & right(late_date,2)

msgbox Cdate(late_date) > Cdate(early_date) 'I would like this to return True, which it does

end sub
```

Comment: It might make more sense to use `DateSerial` if you're concerned about regional settings. A bit of a guess on my part though, since I haven't had to deal with regional settings personally.

Comment: `CDate` does not care about format... It returns a `Date`. This means a `Long` which Excel understands it as `Date`. If you want testing it, simple converting a string looking as a `Date` it will return according to the default System `Date` format. And I am sure that the above suggestion to use `DateSerial` is better. No need to convert anything using `CDate`. `early_date = DateSerial(right(early_date,2) + 2000, CLng(mid(early_date, 3, 2)), CLng(left(early_date,2)))`. It will return a `Date` which can be formatted as yo want. Try `Debug.Print early_date, Format(early_date, "dd/mm/yy")`...

Answer (score 0):

You should always handel dates as *Date*. Try:

```vb
public sub date_test()

    dim early_text  as string '9th June 2020
    dim late_text   as string '4th July 2020 

    dim early_date  as date
    dim late_date   as date

    early_text = "090620"
    late_text = "040720" 

    early_date = DateSerial(right(early_text, 2), mid(early_text, 3, 2), left(early_text, 2))
    late_date = DateSerial(right(late_text, 2), mid(late_text, 3, 2), left(late_text, 2))

    msgbox DateDiff("d", early_date, late_date) > 0

end sub
```